# Google Play Services: Google ladder - How can I customize the share button?

Tags: unity, leaderboards, google-play-services, social

To increase the feeling of competition among users of a [small game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.SharpedStoneStudios.PizzaDrift) that I developed, I implemented a google ladder such that players could measure against other players. To do this, I used the [google play games plugin for unity](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity), which works quite well.

To increase the visibility of the game, I would like to allow the user to share their scores on social platforms, or even via messages.
Looking at this picture:
[image: Share game]
Such a button exists, but only when looking at the social ladder (b) (ranking against your friends), and not overall (a). Additionally, the message is not very interesting (c).
My questions:

- Is it possible to customize this ladder screen such as to add a button on the "All" page?
- Would it be possible to add the share button on the top, rather than bottom?
- Would it be possible to add a custom image featuring the game and the score to the share message, such that the message gets more attractive? Additionally posting the score as an image would mean the user can't change it before posting.

[This question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/115131/how-to-share-unity-high-scores-on-social-media-facebook-google-and-twitter) addresses some of the points I rise here, but not from withing google ladder.